# Using top position affects whole page

Tags: html, css

I have a page with an angled DIV at the top and a `DIV` immediately below that which is angled. I've had to offset the position of both top `DIVs` so that they join together. The only issue is that the next `DIV` below these has a space the size of the `120px` offset.

I could apply this to every DIV but doing this to the footer means that there's empty white space at the bottom of the page.

```css
.top {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF0000, #00FF00);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

.main {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #0000FF;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
  top: -120px;
}

.next {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="next"></div>
```

Any ideas to make the black `DIV` begin at the bottom of the blue one and the rest of the page not be affected would be appreciated, you can't simply use `top: -120px;` on every DIV because then there's `120px` of empty space at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change top by margin-top, it will have the same effect for the element, and the normal flow after it will be the same

```css
.top {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF0000, #00FF00);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

.main {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #0000FF;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.next {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="next"></div>
```